# Android Studio force closes after splash screen

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio for quite a while without any issues. But today when I tried opening AS, nothing happened. I tried again. Nothing happened. Uninstalled. Reinstalled. Updated JDK. Opened again but this time splash screen appears for some milliseconds and closes.

I, most probably, didn't make any change to the system but as far as I remember, I force closed AS a few days ago. This might be the reason but I'm not sure.

After reading some suggestions on the web, I came to know that I need to setup JAVA_HOME Environment variable. I never added before and AS used to work as expected. So I just added this variable just to check and nothing happened.

I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: You did not mention which OS you are using, but try to start AS from the command line and see if there are any errors written to the console.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10. I just tried. Opened the folder of executable. Shift+Right-click. Open command window here. studio64.exe. No errors

Comment: @AnkushBist but it is about "software tools commonly used by programmers" and therefore on-topic. See the help center (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem by removing the **JAVA_OPTIONS** environmental variable whose value was **-Xmx2g**. It directs Android Studio to use 2 GB of RAM for heap although this much memory wasn't available. So it couldn't start.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I had such issue was related to my HDD having bad sectors. Unfortunetly, the last program you access, is the last to write to HDD, in my case it was also AS. I would suggest you to install CrystalDiskInfo and check the condition of your HDD.

Comment: Hi, I had inserted a new SSD just about 20 days ago. Do I still need to check?

Comment: Give it a try, its free, it will inform you right away on the condition. Excluding this case will be a real relief.

Comment: A bit relief. Its showing Good health 100%. What can be the cause then?

Comment: I would do remove the Android Studio folder, usually in /home/[username]/android-studio, after that run registry cleaning tool to remove anything related to it and try to reinstall it again. Also if you are saying that you use windows 10, open the windows update log to see if anything new has been installed or updated there.